# Render pixelated sprite from sprite sheet in React Native without crashing the springboard

Tags: react-native, expo, sprite, nearest-neighbor, sprite-sheet

I'd like to render a non animated pixel art sprite in an image with nearest neighbour upscaling.

My image looks like this and at the moment it renders the entire sprite sheet:

```
<Image
  source={require("../assets/sheet.png")}
  style={{
    width: 30,
    height: 30
  }}
```

In CSS this would be simple to do with `background-size`, `background-position` and `image-rendering: pixelated`.

Comment: I've tried upscaling and using `ImageBackground`. This results in a spring board crash, I assume from the device running out of memory. Under 50 sprites from a 4096px sprite sheet use over 750mb memory, if React Native stores a copy of the image each time- but why else would the spring board crash when adding an extra sprite?